# use uniq -d on a particular column?

Tags: linux, unix

Have a text file like this.

```
john,3
albert,4
tom,3
junior,5
max,6
tony,5
```

I'm trying to fetch records where column2 value is same. My desired output.

```
john,3
tom,3
junior,5
tony,5
```

I'm checking if we can use `uniq -d` on second column?

Comment: I tried this already, it won't work actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It reads the input file twice, but avoids the need to sort:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$2]++; next } a[$2] > 1' file file
```

Results:

```
john,3
tom,3
junior,5
tony,5
```

Brief explanation:

`FNR==NR` is a common AWK idiom that is true for the first file in the arguments list. Here, column two is added to an array and incremented. On the second read of the file, we simply check if the value of column two is greater than one (the `next` keyword skips processing the rest of the code).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  How do I extend this if I have multiple fields in the file and I'm comparing the first and the fourth fields? My output should also be first and four fields.

Comment: @mariswamykantha: If I understand you correctly, I think you can simply use: `awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$4]++; next } a[$1,$4] > 1' file{,}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use uniq on fields (columns), but not easily in your case.

Uniq's `-f` and `-s` options filter by fields and characters respectively. However neither of these quite do what want.

`-f` divides fields by whitespace and you separate them with commas.
`-s` skips a fixed number of characters and your names are of variable length.

Overall though, `uniq` is used to compress input by consolidating duplicates into unique lines. You are actually wishing to retain duplicates and eliminate singletons, which is the opposite of what `uniq` is used to do. It would appear you need a different approach.

Comment: Most definitely. I'm not sure it can be done simply via bash and the command line tools though. Others may wish to weigh in here. It can be done quickly and easily using a scripting language, eg. Perl, Python, etc. It wouldn't take me long in Perl if that's of use to you.